# Explain notation $P\left(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i > 2\log{n} \right) = P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n\{X_i > 2\log(n)\} \right)$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Let the random variable $X_i$ denote the number of probes required by the ith insertion (insert an item $i$ into a hash table of size $m$ and $n$ elements total. Given that  $Pr\{X_i> 2 \log{n}\} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ . Let the random variable $X = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i$ denote the maximum number of probes required by any of the $n$ insertions.

From what I got, we can see that:

$$
\begin{align}
P\left(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i > 2\log{n} \right) =  P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n\{X_i > 2\log(n)\} \right)\tag{1}\label{tag1}\\
P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n\{X_i > 2\log(n)\} \right) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(X_i > 2\log(n)\right) 
\tag{2}\label{tag2}
\end{align}
$$

Sorry if this sounds a bizarre question, but I am not getting here 2 things:

1. Why in \ref{tag1}, how from the $\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}$ on LHS we got $\bigcup_{i=1}^n{}$ on RHS please?
2. In \ref{tag2}, why it's less than given that both are same please?

Comment: I got a hint for 1 question that, $\{ω|max_i X_i(ω)>2log n\}=U_i\{ω|X_i(ω)>2log n\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ is by definition of max. Consider the event

$\left(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i\right) > k $

$\Leftrightarrow \exists{i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$, s.t., $\{X_i>k\}$

$\Leftrightarrow \{X_1 > k\} \lor \{X_2 > k\} \lor \ldots \lor \{X_n > k\}$

$\Leftrightarrow \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n\{X_i > k\}$

Hence, $P \left(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i > k \right) = P( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n\{X_i > k\})$

$(2)$ is by union bound: $P\left( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)$, refer to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality.

Note that LHS and RHS are not the same, they are equal iff the events $A_i$ are disjoint.

Comment: Thank you very much. Events in my question are independent, but that does not mean they are disjoint I guess

Comment: Events $A_i ,A_j$ disjoint means $A_i \cap A_j=\Phi$ (mutually exclusive), i.e., only one of them can occur at a time. Whereas $A_i ,A_j$ independent means $P(A_i|A_j)=P(A_i)$, i.e., occurrence of an event does not influence the prob. of occurrence of another event. In union bound, independence of the events are not required.

Comment: Independence does not rule out the simultaneous occurrence of the events, but if they are disjoint, they can't occur simultaneously. Here $X_i>k$ and $X_j > k$ can be assumed to be independent, since the event that 'the number of probes required to insert the $i^{th}$ element into the hash table is greater than k' does not influence the probability of that of $j^{th}$, but they are not disjoint since it's possible to have $X_i>k$ and $X_j>k$ at the same time.