# If $ X = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i$, then show that $ E [X] = O(\log{n})$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

I have a follow-up question based on my question here please [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245252/explain-notation-p-left-underset1-le-i-le-n-max-x-i-2-logn-right-p).

Let the random variable $X_i$ denote the number of probes required by the ith insertion (insert an item $i$ into a hash table of size $m$ and $n$ elements total. Given that  $Pr\{X_i> 2 \log{n}\} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ . Let the random variable $X = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i$ denote the maximum number of probes required by any of the $n$ insertions.

Here we would like to show that if $ X = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i$, then show that $ E [X] = O(\log{n})$.

**Given**: $X_i's$ are independent. Also given that $P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i \le 2 \log{n}) \le 1$ and $P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i > 2\log{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$.

From what I got,

$$
\begin{align}
$ E[X] = E\left[\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k\times P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right)\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{2\log{n}}\left(k\times P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right) + \sum_{k=2\log{n} +1 }^{n}\left(k\times P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right)\\
\le =\sum_{k=1}^{2\log{n}}\left(2\log{n}\times P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right) + \sum_{k=2\log{n} +1 }^{n}\left(n\times P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right)\\
=2\log{n}\times \sum_{k=1}^{2\log{n}}\left(P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right) + n\times \sum_{k=2\log{n} +1 }^{n}\left( P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i=k) \right)\tag{1} \label{1}\\
=2\log{n}\times \left(P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i \le 2\log{n}) \right) + n\times \left(P(\underset{1\le i\le n}{\max} X_i > 2\log{n}) \right) \tag{2} \label{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

**Problems**:

1. Where did the sum disappear in \ref{2} from \ref{1} please?
2. Can you please show in \ref{2}, how we got $\le 2 \log{n}$ and $> 2 \log{n}$ please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note than the symbol $=$ becomes $\leq$ and $>$ because:
$$\sum_{k=1}^a\mathbf{P}(Y=k)=\mathbf{P}(Y\leq a)=F_Y(a)$$
$$\sum_{k=a+1}^\infty\mathbf{P}(Y=k)=\mathbf{P}(Y>a)=1-F_Y(a)$$
where $F_Y(\cdot)$ is the cdf of Y. Is it understood how to complete the proof?

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this from Cumulative distribution function please?

Comment: The cdf is $F_Y(y)=\mathbf{P}(Y\leq y)$, so the first sum is the cdf and the second one is $1-F_Y(y)$

Comment: Thank you. I mean you got answer to my question based on CDF please? I mean you used facts from CDF since $P(Y≤y) = ∑P(Y=k)$, so we can replace the sum in (1) by $P(max X_i≤2logn)$ for the first one and same for second one

Comment: Is there a lemma, theorem for this please?